# Docker - misunderstanding about the execution and volume

Tags: maven, docker

I have a following Dockerfile in my pet project:

```
FROM java:8
ADD target/sources-registry-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar sources-registry.jar
RUN bash -c 'touch /sources-registry.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/sources-registry.jar"]
EXPOSE 8761
```

And everything perfectly works - image is created and can be run. Now a bit of description about the project: it is a maven based project and before actually executing the Dockerfile I have to manually run `mvn package`.

However, if I change the Dokerfile to (because I do not want manually to run `mvn package` and want to automate it)

```
FROM java:8
RUN ls target
RUN ./mvnw package
ADD target/sources-registry-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar sources-registry.jar
RUN bash -c 'touch /sources-registry.jar'
#ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/sources-registry.jar"]
EXPOSE 8761
```

then while execution I get `/bin/sh: 1: ./mvnw: not found`. However, `mvnw` is in my project files near the `pom.xml`.

Even more if I just do following Dockerfile

```
FROM java:8
RUN ls target/
```

then I get `ls: cannot access target/: No such file or directory`.

Can someone please explain this behaviour?

1. I mean why I can actually do something with target folder (first
   Dockerfile) even if does not exist (third Dockerfile)?
2. How project files (and what files) get copied into a created
   container?
3. The main question: Why second Dockerfile is not working? And how I can make it work?

Comment: The `mvnw..` is the Maven Wrapper which will download Maven and furthermore will run the `package` lifecycle which means to download all necessary dependencies/plugins etc. and finally build the resulting jar files which you are interested in. I would suggest to build the needed artifact outside the docker container and only copy the final jar file into the container...Apart from that if you execute something inside the contains it must be available inside the container which is not the case cause you have top copy either the files into the container or mount a volume into the container...

Comment: BTW: What is coming into my mind you might use multi-stage builds in Docker which could help here...

Answer (score 1):

The ADD command copies over the `sources-registry.jar` file into the Docker image, so that the first example is able to execute it. If you want to use any other files inside the container, you need to include them in the image as well (using ADD or COPY). See [the reference docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) for more information

Comment: So I basically need to copy all project files to the container in order to be able to run `./mvnw package`?

Comment: If so, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: I don't really know what are the requirement of this Maven command, but the safest bet is to use `COPY . .` which recursively copies over all files from the current directory (first dot) to the work directory of the Docker image (second dot).